# How to prevent Migrate from creating null fields?

Tags: 7, migrations

I'm writing some migrations classes using Migrate module. Some of my source fields does not have data for migration but the Migrate module creates Drupal fields with `null` values anyway. How to prevent that? I only want to create fields if there are non-null values for them.

[This comment](https://drupal.org/node/1133448#comment-7528031) suggests that it should be enough to just unset field from source row (for example inside `prepareRow`), but that doesn't work for me - the field with `null` value is created anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [this feature](https://drupal.org/node/1792894) was added to Migrate 2.6 and for now is available only when you're using dev version. For those who want to try it out, there is [RC1 version](https://drupal.org/node/2029049) available.

For older Migrate module versions, the empty field needs to be unset in **`prepare`** function, **not** inside `prepareRow` as [the comment](https://drupal.org/node/1133448#comment-7528031) from drupal docs page suggested. Here is an example:

```
function prepare($entity, $row) {
  // Assuming that 'year' maps to 'field_year'
  if (!isset($row->year) || $row->year === null)
    unset($entity->field_year);

  // Assuming that 'gender' maps to 'field_gender'
  if (!isset($row->gender) || $row->gender === null)
    unset($entity->field_gender);
}
```

There is also a more *"generic"* solution prosed in one of the [comments on drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/1792894#comment-6799706) (pasting it here for future reference):

```
/**
 * Removes empty values prior to migrating.
 * @see http://drupal.org/node/1665332
 * @see http://drupal.org/node/1792894
 */
function mymodule_remove_empties($destination, $entity) {
  if ($destination instanceof MigrateDestinationEntity) {
    $entity_type = $destination->getEntityType();
    $form = $form_state = array();
    _field_invoke_default('submit', $entity_type, $entity, $form, $form_state);
  }
}
```

And in each of your Migrate classes:

```
public function prepare($entity, stdClass $source_row) {
  mymodule_remove_empties($this->destination, $entity);
}
```